# How do i draw random shapes in different JPanels in Java

Tags: java, swing, random, jpanel

I am trying to make a small version of a slot machine. I am using five `JPanel`s. Four of the `JPanel`s will hold random shapes like a square, circle, and oval. If all four of the `JPanel`s are displaying a square then the fifth `JPanel` should display `JackPot` and if any other combination is displayed then the fifth `JPanel` should say try again. The problem I am having is making the fifth `JPanel` display a message when the user wins or loses. I am able to draw the shapes randomly on the `JPanel`s but the problem I am having is making the paint method draw in a specific `JPanel`. When I run the code a random shape appears on every `JPanel` but I only want the shapes to appear on four `JPanel`s instead of all five.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class JackPot extends JPanel {

    public JackPot(Color backColor) {
        setBackground(backColor);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Random gen = new Random();
        int a = gen.nextInt(10);

        if (a <= 3) {
              g.drawOval(20,20,25,25);
        } else if (a > 3 && a <= 6) {
            g.drawRect(20,20,25,10);
        } else {
            g.drawOval(20,20,20,10);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame GUI = new JFrame();
        GUI.setTitle("JackPot");
        GUI.setSize(500, 400);

        Container pane = GUI.getContentPane();
        pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 1));
        JackPot panel = new JackPot(Color.red);
        JackPot panel2 = new JackPot(Color.white);
        JackPot panel3 = new JackPot(Color.yellow);
        JackPot panel4 = new JackPot(Color.green);
        JackPot panel5 = new JackPot(Color.pink);

        pane.add(panel);
        pane.add(panel2);
        pane.add(panel3);
        pane.add(panel4);
        pane.add(panel5);

        GUI.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        GUI.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow. 2) A single blank line of white space in source code is *always* enough.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant.

Comment: Fixed code formatting, edited to be peer reviewed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Your 5th `JPanel` should *not* be a `JackPot` object but rather it's own object, perhaps a `PayoutPanel` object or something similar. The key is that its behavior is intrinsically different from that of `JackPot` and so its code must be different to match.
2. You need to get your program logic *out* of your `paintComponent` method. The logic should not be triggered by a repaint, but rather by an explicit method call, since you cannot fully control repaints.
3. You should give your spinning components a method to allow other objects to extract their state, so that they all can be compared.

Comment: I see what you are saying. The only problem is that the Java class I'm in hasn't covered methods yet so I am forced to use the paint method and main class.

Comment: @user3076906: Your Java class "hasn't covered methods yet"?? Are you saying that you're being instructed to create Swing GUI programs without knowing how to create or override a method? Seriously? I find this very difficult to believe.

Comment: thanks for the help. I asked my friend and he showed me a way to do it. It isn't the best way but it works. I ended up creating a different class for each shape and for the additional panels telling the user if they won or lost. I then used a random generator and drew a shape depending on the result. I used a counter to check how many squares were on the JPanel so when I had a count of 4 I called my Win class which had the JPanel that said Jackpot.